# Can I save a C static library anywhere I want?

Tags: c, static-libraries, static-linking

I have created a library in C and want to link it when compiled. Do I have to save in a certain folder in my computer's file system or can I create my own file structure within my application to save it?

Update: My error turned out to be not properly including a header file. My files and linker were fine but it was simple syntax error.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the accepted answer there talks about `rpath`, that has nothing to do with what OP asked. OP is talking about *static* libraries.

Comment: Ok, retracting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save it wherever you want. Just make sure that the compiler knows the location. In the case of `gcc` for example, you can use:

```
gcc -L path/to/libdir -l:mylib.a ...
```

(assuming `mylib.a` is in `path/to/libdir`)

Or even:

```
gcc path/to/libdir/mylib.a ...
```

Comment: Agreed. Just nitpicking, but it is the linker that needs to know the location; the compiler in this case just calls the linker (ld) for the user's convenience.

Comment: That's true of course, but since it's the compiler that calls the linker, the compiler needs to know it. The wording is consistent, I didn't want to overcomplicate.

Comment: Since you do not need the compiler to call the linker, the compiler does not _need_ to know it.

Comment: Hmm, yes. It's not clear whether OP already has the needed objects and just wants to link or not. Either way, `gcc` works for both purposes.

Comment: @usr That depends on what you call "seperately". After all, everything is on a single disk image, isn't it

Comment: @usr that is very necessary, 99.9999999% of the times, yes.

Comment: @usr Compiler and Linker do different things: A compiler generates the machine code and the linker produces the final executable. This is even necessary when only a single object file and no library dependencies exist.

Comment: (this conversation is exactly why I intentionally chose not to talk about the linker)

Comment: Why do you dislike conversations? This is one of the better comparef to others on this site ;)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I got a linking error and wasn't sure if the compiler automatically would look in the /usr/lib file instead of where I specified.